# Checking all the check boxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I want to implement a scenario-
There is present a checkbox on the top of the screen and there is a custom listview with checkboxes below that top checkbox.

I want that one someone checks that checkbox all the listview checkboxes should be checked and vice versa.

```
public class GroupMemberListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        Context Mycontext;

        public GroupMemberListAdapter(Context context) {
            Mycontext = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return broadcastList.size();

        }

        public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
            return paramInt;
        }

        public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
            return paramInt;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            EventViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactcustomlayout,
                        null);
                holder = new EventViewHolder();

                holder.mtvGroupMemberName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvGroupMemberName);

                holder.checkbox_group_member = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_GroupMember);

                /*holder.mtvGroupMemberAbout = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvGroupMemberAbout);*/

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (EventViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.mtvGroupMemberName.setText(""+broadcastList.get(position));
            //holder.mtvGroupMemberAbout.setText(""+data.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }

        public class EventViewHolder {
            private TextView mtvGroupMemberName;
            private TextView mtvGroupMemberAbout;
            private CheckBox checkbox_group_member;
        }
    } 


checkBox_selectAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                checkAllBoxes();

            }
        });


    private void checkAllBoxes(){

        int size =  mlvGroupBroadContact.getAdapter().getCount();
        System.out.println("Size of the list is:"+size);


    }
```

How can I check all the list view boxes???

Answer (score 1):

If your `ListView`'s choice mode is `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` or `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`:

```
    private void deselectAll() {

        getListView().clearChoices(); 

       //--as of GingerBread, clearChoices() alone is not sufficient--
       //--we'd have to manually un-check visible items--

        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getChildCount(); i++) {
            View c = getListView().getChildAt(i);
            if (c instanceof Checkable) {
                ((Checkable) c).setChecked(false);
            }
        }

    }

    private void selectAll() {

        SparseBooleanArray sba = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();

        for (int i = 0; i < getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
            sba.put(i, true);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < getListView().getChildCount(); i++) {
            View c = getListView().getChildAt(i);
            if (c instanceof Checkable) {
                ((Checkable) c).setChecked(true);
            }
        }

    }
```

Replace `getListView()` and `getAdapter()` with your `ListView` and its `Adapter` instances.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code to check all checkboxes in the listview

```
private void checkAllBoxes(){

    int size =  mlvGroupBroadContact.getAdapter().getCount();
    System.out.println("Size of the list is:"+size);
    CheckBox chk;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      chk= ((CheckBox)jobList.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.chk));
      chk.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update a Boolean variable in your adapter class from on checkBox_selectAll click listner.
and call view.getAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

In getView based on this variable set it state checked or unchecked.